How to make whenever gem work on my rails app?
I am currently creating an "habit tracker" app and wish to create an instance of my model Day everyday. I tried to implemant de whenever gem on my app, but it doesn't seem to work (no new instance, nor if i try minutes, hours or days); I've followed every tuto online (here, youtube, ...), restarted the process from scratch... nothing.
Here are my codes:
schedule.rb
every 3.minute do
  command "cd /Users/myusername/code/myusername/habit-tracker && bundle exec rails runner 'Day.create!'"
end

set :environment, "development"


# every 1.minute do
#   command "bundle exec rails runner Day.create!"
#   rake 'batch:create_day', environment: "development"
#   runner 'Day.create!', environment: "development"
# end

# every :minute do
#   command "bundle exec rails runner Day.create!"
#   rake 'batch:create_day', environment: "development"
#   runner 'Day.create!', environment: "development"
# end


batch.rake
namespace :batch do
  desc "Create a new instance of Day everyday"
  task create_day: :environment do
    Day.create!
  end
end

contrab -l
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/myusername/code/myusername/habit-tracker/config/schedule.rb at: 2024-04-30 17:17:19 +0200
0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/myusername/code/myusername/habit-tracker && bundle exec rails runner '\''Day.create!'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/myusername/code/myusername/habit-tracker/config/schedule.rb at: 2024-04-30 17:17:19 +0200

I've followed every tuto online (here, youtube, ...), restarted the process from scratch... nothing.
EDIT:
I don't have any error message, I ran "whenever --update-crontab" and "bundle exec whenever" every time I updated the schedule file
and i got:
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/myusername/code/myusername/habit-tracker && bundle exec rails runner '\''Day.create!'\'' >> log/cron_error.log 2>&1'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.

I am on macos so "sudo service cron status" doesn't work, is there any other command I could try ?

rake 'batch:create_day' does not work?

Why not just create 10,000 day records at once and then you won't have to worry about it until 2050?

Anton Bogdanov - yes it does !

max - i'm new to rails i don't know how to do such thing

First make sure cron is running with
sudo service cron status

Have you run the following commands to add the content of the schedule file to crontab?
whenever --update-crontab
crontab -r

For seeing the output you could add the following line to the schedule.rb
set :output, './log/example.log'

Make sure to run again
whenever --update-crontab
crontab -r


Spinning up a worker to insert one record per day is a pretty silly solution as it's trival to for example create 10 years worth of records in a one time task.
namespace :batch do
  desc "Create ten years worth of day records"
    task create_year: :environment do
      # This range spans from todays date to 10 years into the future
      rng = (Date.current..Date.current.advance(years: 10))
      # We convert the range into an array of hashes  
      attributes = rng.map {|date| { created_at: date } }
      # All the records are inserted in a single query
      Day.insert_all(attributes)
    end
  end
end

This is only inserting 1827 rows so the run time is just a second or two.

Hey ! thanks a lot, I tried it but it created 1827 instances of today...

Well, you didn't actually tell me how you're storing the date. Given that you're storing it in the created_at column Day.last.created_at gives Sat, 06 May 2034.
